# Vaadin 10 Grid add custom image icon

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin10

I am using a Vaadin 10 (Flow) `Grid` to stream data to new rows, and I am trying to add a custom image icon to my `TemplateRenderer`.

I have a `TemplateRenderer` setup like this:

```
TemplateRenderer<TradeUni> sizee = TemplateRenderer.<TradeUni>
            of("<div class$=\"[[item.class]]\">[[item.size]]</div>")
            .withProperty("class", cssClassProvider)
            .withProperty("size", TradeUni::getSize);
```

Which displays my numbers correctly in the grid cell like this:

[image]

I would like to have my image rendered inside the same cell, to the left of the numbers.

This was my (very crude) attempt to import it using html:

```
TemplateRenderer<TradeUni> sizee = TemplateRenderer.<TradeUni>
            of("<div class$=\"[[item.class]]\"><img src=\"i.imgur.com/3LQBglR.png\">[[item.size]]</div>")
            .withProperty("class", cssClassProvider)
            .withProperty("size", TradeUni::getSize);
```

Which give's me this:

[image]

I think that I might have to wrap the image and numbers into a `HorizontalLayout` with the image being a separate component - I think I could handle that, but I am unsure of how to do the actual rendering of the image.  I can probably accomplish it simply with the internal Vaadin Icons set, but I need to use my own little images.. all icons that I am going to use will be at or less than 25 x 25px.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the right track, but there's one small detail that causes you trouble. The URL `i.imgur.com/3LQBglR.png` doesn't define a protocol, which means that the entire string will be treated as a path relative to the location of the hosting page. It will thus try to find a file in a directory named `i.imgur.com` on your own server.

To fix this, you need to also include the protocol in the image URL, i.e. `https://i.imgur.com/3LQBglR.png`.

I can also offer a small suggestion for how to make the code easier to read. HTML also supports using `'` for enclosing attribute values. This is more convenient to use from Java string since you don't need to use `\` to escape `'` characters. Your template string could thus be `"<div class$='[[item.class]]'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/3LQBglR.png'>[[item.size]]</div>"`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Leif :D